# ScaleGrid MySQL connection refused error HY000/2002

Tags: mysql, connection-refused

ScaleGrid MySQL service shows connection refused error when i try to connect from my NodeJS TypeORM application and also from CLI. Tried providing ssl ca certificate but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Adding firewall rule to whitelist IP solves the issue.
Firewall rules tab can be found in Overview section in Dashboard. Firewall rules can also be defined at the account level rules in Settings tab.

To set the database internet visible you can add IP CIDR as 0.0.0.0/0 (Not recommended). This will make it public accessible.